# How to skip an object using the automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, automapper

I've got the following DataModels:

```
class TicketDM
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public List<NoteContractDM> Notes{get;set;}
}

class NoteContractDM
{
 public NoteDM Note{get;set;}
}

class NoteDM{
 public string Subject{get;set;}
 public string Description{get;set}
}
```

And the following ViewModels:

```
public class TicketVM
{
 public int Id {get;set;
 public List<NoteVM> Notes{get;set;}
}

public NoteVM
{
 public string Subject{get;set;}
 public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

I want to do some automapping, and to do that I have to skip the noteContractDM. The following obviously doesnt work:

`Mapper.CreateMap<TicketDM, TicketVM>()`

I tried something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TicketDM, TicketVM>()
  .ForMember(vm => vm.Notes, conf => conf.MapFrom(dm => dm.Notes));
```

But it always gives me the `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.` exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell Automapper to ignore them if you want to skip the object:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TicketDM, TicketVM>()
.ForMember(vm => vm.Notes, conf => conf.Ignore());
```

But by the example you are giving, you may want to create another map so `Notes` can also get mapped automatically:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TicketDM, TicketVM>()
.ForMember(vm => vm.Notes, conf => conf.MapFrom(dm => dm.Notes.Select(x => x.Note)));

Mapper.CreateMap<NoteDM, NoteVM>();
```

(example uses System.Linq)